# How to Get All of the Unique Attributes in an Observablelist and Count the Unique Attributes?

Tags: java

I have an `ObservalbeList<Appointment> appointments`. Each `appointment` has a `type` attribute that is a String and can return the `type` with a `getType()` method. Ideally if the appointments list had "General, Review, Weekly, Weekly" the output would be:

```
General: 1, 
Review: 1,  
Weekly: 2
```

While I can iterate through the List I'm having trouble tracking the unique values and the count of those values.

Is there a recommended way I can implement this? Below is what I currently have.

```java
    public void clickMenuReportsItemNumberOfAppointmentsByType(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

        TextAreaOutput.clear();

        AppointmentDOA appointmentDOA = new AppointmentDOA(DBConnection.getConnection());
        ObservableList<Appointment> Appointments = appointmentDOA.findAll();

        // get all the types
        // check the number of times each type shows up
        ObservableList<String> type = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        for(int i =0; i < Appointments.size(); i++){
            Appointments.get(i).getType();
            if(!type.contains(Appointments.get(i).getType())){
                type.add(Appointments.get(i).getType());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the Java 8 stream api:

```
ObservableList<Appointment> Appointments = appointmentDOA.findAll();

Map<String, Long> appointmentsMap = appointments.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Appointment::getType, Collectors.counting()));
```

You will get a Map with the Appointment types (Strings) as keys and the count as values. Additionally, I'd recommend to use a Java Enum for the appointment types:

```
enum AppointmentType {General, Review, Weekly};

ObservableList<Appointment> Appointments = appointmentDOA.findAll();

Map<AppointmentType, Long> appointmentsMap = appointments.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Appointment::getType, Collectors.counting()));
```